# Jquery Fancybox title is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, photo-gallery

I have a fancybox photo gallery that is working properly but I'm trying to add titles to the photos and I cannot get them to appear at all.

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />

<a data-fancybox="gallery" class="party" title="I met Anna in 2007 while in college at NAU in Flagstaff, AZ." href="images/anna.jpeg">
    <img class="smig" src="images/anna.jpeg">
</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.party").fancybox({
      helpers : {
          title: {
              type: 'inside'
          }
      }
  });
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

From docs http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage -

> A caption can be added using the `data-caption` attribute

But, if you want to use `title` attribute, you can easily customize like this:

```
$( '[data-fancybox="gallery"]' ).fancybox({
  caption : function( instance, item ) {
    return $(this).attr('title');
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bojEmQ?editors=1010

btw, you are using options from v2 that do not exist in v3.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to set js in $(document).ready

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a.party").fancybox({
         helpers : {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
         }
      });
  });
```

Comment: it already is, sorry I forgot to put that. I've tried it outside of the doc ready as well